# Drupal: Duplicate blog tags showing in block

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-views

I've got a Druapl-based website with a blog.  I'm using a custom view block to list the different tags I've assigned to my posts.  Although it lists them just fine (links work fine too), I'm getting alot of duplicates.  For example, if I tag 3 differents posts with "sometag", then my block lists "sometag" 3 times in a row.

How do I fix this so each tag only appears ONCE in the block?

View export (in PHP): http://pastebin.com/m7b4724b7

View screenshot: http://i49.tinypic.com/2vmsthk.gif

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select Term at Views creation, not Node.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Click the little cog next to Style: HTML List, and select group by Taxonomy: Term.it.
2. Do as Nikit suggested and do a Taxonomy view instead of a Node view. That way, you can just select to filter duplicates and it will work as expected (by filtering duplicate terms instead of duplicate nodes)

Either should work fine. Just do whatever makes more sense to you.

Comment: First option (grouping) didn't give me the exact result I wanted, but option two did.  Thanks for the help!